# What is the preferred way of adding a "None" class to a classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, classification

Suppose I have some classifier where the model is just `y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b` which I then softmax to get probabilities, like this:

```
{
 "dog_bark": "53.2912",
 "siren": "46.7088"
}
```

but I want it to look more like this:

```
{
   "dog_bark": "0.25",
   "siren": "0.25",
   "none": "99.5"
}
```

I know I could add a none class with random feature sets, but that seems hacky and time consuming. I'm not even sure that would be accurate - since a real world say, bear is probably closer to dog bark than random data. Is there some preferred method to accomplish a none class, or some similar affect?

(Also ideally not fudging the probability that it IS none)

Comment: How would a model like this determine the probability for classifying new data as "none"? That doesn't seem possible with at least some prior on often it should output "none."

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have access to the real examples of "none" class and you do not want hacky solutions (like generating them, suggested in the question), the only approach remaining is to learn a generative model instead of discriminative one. In other words, if you learn P(x|y) and P(y) for each (observed) y, then you also have P(x) = SUM_i P(x|y=i)P(y=i), which is the probability of belonging to **any** of the classes you have seen. The only thing missing is to set a threshold T (or more complex method of deciding) under which you put a sample to the "none" class. Unfortunately learning a generative model is usually much harder than typical discriminative ones, but your problem is also much harder (since you want your model to be "aware of non-observed samples"). Alternatively you can learn P(x) independently from your classifier, and use it as "pre-filtering" of your data, so lets say you learn P(x) using some density estimation technique (GMM, KDE, etc.), and then you classify according to:

```
NEW_P(y=i|x) = P(x)*P(y=i|x)
NEW_P(y=none|x) = 1-P(x)
```

It is easy to show that the above is valid probability, since `NEW_P(y=none|x) + SUM_i NEW_P(y=i|x) = 1-P(x) + P(x) SUM_i P(y=i|x) = 1-P(x) + P(x)*1 = 1`.

In short, what you are doing now gives you only P(y=i|x), and the whole trick with discriminative learning is that you can omit P(x). For the problem you are considering you actually need it (unless you want hacky things / gathering data). And there are at least a few ways of learning (and using) it.